# Getting issue in laravel while installing Jenssegers\Mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5.2 & installing **Jenssegers\Mongodb**  using command line. But i am getting following issue.

**Problem 1**

- mongodb/mongodb 1.0.2 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
- mongodb/mongodb 1.0.2 requires ext-mongodb ^1.1.0 -> the requested PHP extension mongodb is missing from your system.
- Installation request for mongodb/mongodb (locked at 1.0.2) -> satisfiable by mongodb/mongodb[1.0.2].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:

  - /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
  - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/05-opcache.ini
  - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
  - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
  - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
  - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-mongo.ini
  - /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

I have already added extension=mongo.so in /etc/php5/cli/php.ini. I am using ubuntu 15.04 and using default apache2 server.

I am using MongoDB 3.2.6 version.

Please let me know what is the issue ?

Thanks

Comment: Please add ""jenssegers/mongodb": "*"," to your composer.json in root folder of laravel project.It's work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this code

```
sudo apt-get install php-mongodb
```

Comment: Unable to find package